# Crystal report 2008 User Defined Page Layout

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to set the Report Layout on client side So User can set report's layout Which may be Portrait OR Landscape after report shown. So user will have the option if data comes on half page then he can use landscape to print Report Otherwise Portrait.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to design two different report layouts in one RPT file and pick one at runtime, that's not really possible. If you're just wanting to know how to set the orientation, here are the properties for doing that:

```
cryRpt.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperOrientation.Landscape
cryRpt.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperOrientation.Portrait
cryRpt.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperOrientation.DefaultPaperOrientation
```